# How to stop li width from matching its child li

Tags: jquery, css, menu, html-lists

Hopefully the last part of this menu I've been working on. It've got the submenu dropdown going horizontal like the main part of the navigation, but the child li get's larger with each li, of coarse, and the issue is the parent is trying to match the width of it's child li. I've tried keeping the child li width on auto and assigning a width to the parent, but either I'm picking all the wrong numbers, or it's not working because everytime I assign a width to the parent it makes the dropdown go vertical instead. My host server also seems to be not updating correctly every time I send on ftp, so it's becoming very difficult to type in random sizes and see what I need to match what I have.

The jsFiddle link shows it all, but I could not get the body onload to hide the submenus to work: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eETjb/)

So it might be best to view the test site as well: [Test Site](http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/fileshare2/index2.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain parent child hierarchy in this case like -

```
#navigation li ul.sub_navigation li{......}
```

updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eETjb/2/

Comment: That fixes it with 2 li as sub, but I need the possibility of, say, 10 sub li. It just stacks after 2 li with that. Which I see what you did, but, if possible, I need the child li to be independent of the parent on width completely.

Comment: You have to follow the same hierarchy process for all child menus

Comment: I'm talking about the multiple li's in #navigation li ul.sub_navigation li{......}, the li's that this class coveres. Your solution does fix my short term problem, but not the long one. Check out my test site again in the link on op. You'll see what I mean. 3 li's are added there, I'm planning on supporting up to 10.

Comment: It ended up being helpful using the hierarchy instead with just 1 id. Doing this helped me see where I needed to put my floats and so forth. Putting the wrong things in the wrong places and going back through positioning is what fixed it. Thanks Dipaks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you should want dropdown menu

i created some example check it

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navi">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home3</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>

</ul>
```

**Css**

```
ul, ul li{
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navi, .submenu{
  list-style:none;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.navi > li{
background:green;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  position:relative;
}
.navi li a{
color:white;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.navi li .submenu{
display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:39px;
  left:0;
}
.navi li:hover .submenu{
display:block;
}
.submenu > li{
display:block;
background:red;
}

.submenu li > a{
border-top:2px solid black;
display:block;
}
```

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/GoDsKf4n

Comment: I appreciate it, but mine is fulling horiztonal. I started out this way but changed my mind. :)